# Is there a concentric map from the disk onto the ellipse with constant sum of singular values?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, singular-values

$\newcommand{Vol}{\text{Vol}}$

Let $c > 2$, and let $0<b<1$ be fixed parameters. Does there exist a $C^1$ monotone bijection $\psi:(0,1] \to (0,1]$, and a $C^1$ function $h:(0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy
$$( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} F+\frac{F}{r})^2+(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} F-h'F)^2=c^2, \,\,\, \text{ for } \, \, \, (r,\theta) \in (0,1] \times [0,2\pi], \tag{1}$$
where $F$ is given in polar coordinates by $$F(r,\theta):=\psi(r)R\big(\theta+h(r)\big), R(\theta):=\frac{b}{\sqrt{1-\big(e \cos(\theta)\big)^2}}, e=\sqrt{1-b^4}.$$

Using the definition of $F$, one gets
$$( \frac{\psi'}{\psi}+\frac{R'}{R}h'+\frac{1}{r})^2+(\frac{1}{r}\frac{R'}{R}-h')^2=\frac{c^2}{F^2},  \tag{2}$$

where $R=R\big(\theta+h(r)\big),R'=R'\big(\theta+h(r)\big)$ implicitly depend on $r,\theta$.

I tried to consider $h$ as a given, and "solve" for $\psi$, but so far without definite progress.

---

Motivation: $(R(\theta),\theta)$ are the polar coordinates of the ellipse $$E=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \,  (\frac{x}{\frac{1}{b}})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2=1\},\,\,\,\, e \,\text{ is the eccentricity.}$$  Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit disk, and let $$f:D\setminus\{0\} \to \tilde D=\{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 \, | \,  0<(\frac{x}{\frac{1}{b}})^2+(\frac{y}{b})^2 \le 1\}$$ be given in polar coordinates by
$$ \big(r,\theta\big )\mapsto \bigg(\psi(r)R\big(\theta+h(r)\big),\theta+h(r)\bigg). \tag{3}$$
$f$ maps the circle of radius $r$ onto a scaled copy of $E$; the scale is given by $\psi$, and the "phase" is given by $h$. The PDE $ \sigma_1(df)+\sigma_2(df)=c $ reduces to the ODE $(1)$, where $ \sigma_1(df),\sigma_2(df)$ are the singular values of $df$.

---

The condition $c > 2$ comes from the AM-GM inequality.
If $\sigma_1+\sigma_2=c$, then $Jf =\sigma_1 \sigma_2 \le (\frac{c}{2})^2$. Thus $$ \Vol(D)=\Vol(\tilde D)=\Vol(f(D))= \int_{D} Jf \le \Vol(D) (\frac{c}{2})^2,$$
which implies $c \ge 2$. If $c=2$, then $\sigma_1 \sigma_2=Jf=1$ which together with $\sigma_1 +\sigma_2=2$ implies $\sigma_1= \sigma_2=1$ so $f$ is an isometry from the disk onto the interior of an ellipse, which is a contradiction.